# SQL for calculated column that chooses from value in own row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in which several indentifiers of a person may be stored. In this table I would like to create a single calculated identifier column that stores the best identifier for that record depending on what identifiers are available.

For example (some fictional sample data) ....

Table = "Citizens"

```
Id | LastName | DL-No        | SS-No          | State-Id-No   | Calculated
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Smith    | NULL         | 374-784-8888   | 7383204848    | ?
2  | Jones    | JG892435262  | NULL           | NULL          | ?
3  | Trask    | TSK73948379  | NULL           | 9276542119    | ?
4  | Clinton  | CL231429888  | 543-123-5555   | 1840430324    | ?
```

I know the order in which I would like choose identifiers ...

1. Drivers-License-No
2. Social-Security-No
3. State-Id-No

So I would like the calculated identifier column to be part of the table schema. The desired results would be ...

```
Id | LastName | DL-No        | SS-No          | State-Id-No   | Calculated
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Smith    | NULL         | 374-784-8888   | 7383204848    | 374-784-8888
2  | Jones    | JG892435262  | NULL           | 4537409273    | JG892435262
3  | Trask    | NULL         | NULL           | 9276542119    | 9276542119
4  | Clinton  | CL231429888  | 543-123-5555   | 1840430324    | CL231429888
```

IS this possible? If so what SQL would I use to calculate what goes in the "Calculated" column?

I was thinking of something like ..

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ([DL-No] is NOT NULL) THEN [DL-No]
    WHEN ([SS-No] is NOT NULL) THEN [SS-No]
    WHEN ([State-Id-No] is NOT NULL) THEN [State-Id-No]
    AS "Calculated"
  END
FROM Citizens
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `coalesce()`:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce([DL-No], [SS-No], [State-ID-No]) as calculated
from citizens c
```

However, I think your `case` statement will also work, if you fix the syntax to use `when` rather than `where`.

Comment: How would one go about creating a second column that contained the type of Calculated Identifier (DL-No, SS-No, or State-Id-No)